# Getting double message notifications after replacing Talk with Hangouts

Tags: google-talk, google-hangouts

I've updated Google Talk to "Hangouts (replaces Talk)". Now whenever I get a message, I receive two notifications: one from the new Hangouts app and the other from the old Talk app. How do I disable the notification from Talk?

Device is Samsung Galaxy S II running Android 4.1.2.

Comment: Hmm, Hangouts seems to have truly replaced Talk on my AT&T SGS3 (I can't remember whether it was built in or I installed it from Google Play, though). But try this: `Settings` ->  `Application Manager` -> `All` (tab) -> `Talk` (maybe `Google Talk`) -> `Disable`. Or you could try going into Talk's settings and disabling anything related to notifications.

Comment: @TreborRude the app menu no longer contains "Talk" so I can't access its settings. In the application manager, neither "Talk" nor "Google Talk" appear under the "all" tab.

Comment: They just changed the app's *name*. If you take a closer look: the *package name* is still the same for hangout: [com.google.android.talk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk). So it's technically impossible to have both apps installed at the same time (unless manipulating one of them into using another package name).

Comment: What happens when one is built in and the other downloaded, @Izzy? There must be some reason he's getting double notifications. That couldn't happen if the app was completely replaced. Stray service? Have you rebooted since installing Hangouts, @Oak?

Comment: @TreborRude it gets "overlayed". What do you think happens with all the updates of the *Google Play* app, which is a system app as well? As for the double notifications: admitted it sounds strange, but it must have another cause. Might be some "stray service" which (whyever) was not "cancelled" on update, so a reboot sounds like a good idea which should solve it in that case.

Comment: @TreborRude just tried a reboot and it solved it. I guess I need to watch The IT Crowd some more :) please post an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: I have the same problem, but a reboot doesn't solve it. I posted a new question: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46060/30136

Comment: The answer in this post helped me out:
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46060/double-message-notifications-after-upgrading-talk-to-hangouts-cyanogenmod-7-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Izzy pointed out in the comments, the package name of Hangouts is the same as the one for Google Talk: `com.google.android.talk`. Therefore, even if Talk was built in to your ROM, it should be 'overlaid' by Hangouts.

However, it's possible that there's some Google Talk service that didn't get killed by the upgrade process. If that's the case, a simple reboot should solve the problem.

Comment: I am having the same issue with my HTC Incredible 2.  This issue has persisted after a reboot.

Comment: Several reboots did not fix error

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem. I solved it by doing the following:

- Settings
- Applications
- Manage applications
- Tab 'All'
- Google Services Framework
- Clear data
- reboot the phone

Good luck

Comment: After following these instructions, my hangouts were no longer being notified of new messages.  I ended up clearing data of Hangouts. Uninstalling Google Play Services, then when I launched Hangouts, it had me re-install Google Play Services.  After install I had to re-open Hangouts twice and then it was working correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If a reboot doesn't solve the problem, such as in my case (HTC Desire HD), try going to Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > All > Hangouts and tap "Clear Cache" and "Clear Data". Go back, open Hangouts again and it will sign you back in. You may need to verify your number again, but that got rid of the duplicate notifications for my case.

Answer (score 3):

This is now fixed in the latest release of Hangouts:

> Fixed a problem where you could receive two notifications for a message: one from Hangouts, one from the old Talk app.

The new version details are below:

UPDATED:
June 6, 2013
CURRENT VERSION:
1.0.2.695251
REQUIRES ANDROID:
2.3 and up

[Google Hangouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed mine a different way. tried all the above and nothing worked. I figured it was still seeing me as logged into Talk.

Try the following:
Uninstall updates for Hangouts. (brings you back to talk)
Open Talk and Sign Out.
Reinstall update (brings you back to Hangouts)

Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this will work, but you could try and install "Root Uninstaller" and remove Google Talk, and then just install hangouts.
In the app you have the option to back it up, so if something goes wrong you can restore your google talk back.

Comment: This led me on the right track: I did not use Root Uninstaller, but followed [these instructions](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Barebones) on the CM wiki to completely remove the system `Talk.apk`.

Comment: Alas, removing `Talk.apk` did not solve it after all.

Comment: So you are still looking for a fix on this?