# Double message notifications after upgrading Talk to Hangouts (CyanogenMod 7.2)

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-talk, notification-bar, troubleshooting, google-hangouts

- Phone: HTC Wildfire
- OS: CyanogenMod-7.2.0-buzz

I recently upgraded Talk to Hangouts, and now each incoming message results in two notifications: one styled like the old Talk, and one from Hangouts.

I tried rebooting the phone, as suggested by [Getting double message notifications after replacing Talk with Hangouts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45779/getting-double-message-notifications-after-replacing-talk-with-hangouts), but the problem still persists.

Looking through the lists of installed applications and running processes, I only see Hangouts, not Talk.

I considered completely uninstalling both Hangouts and Talk, and reinstalling Hangouts, but the application manager only gives me the option of uninstalling the updates for Hangouts, and reverting back to the system's built-in version (of Talk, presumably).

How can I stop the double notifications, or troubleshoot this further?